# memory_order_relaxed only guarantees atomicity and not visibility?

Tags: c++, c, atomic

Given the below C code:

```
static atomic_int a_i;

static void f() 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
     atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&a_i, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

And two threads concurrently calling `f()`.

Is it the case that `a_i` may end up having a non `200` result in hardware platforms with a relaxed cache coherency protocol (unlike x86)? In other words, the operation is atomic but no guarantees that the writes by one thread would be publicly visible immediately to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting value is guaranteed to be 200.

The memory order argument is only about which *other* modifications are made visible to other threads. `memory_order_relaxed` means that no guarantees are made. But the variable itself is still updated atomically.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that. The C++ concurrency book (2nd ed), page 154, appears to state the opposite.

Comment: `shared_ptr` implementations typically use `memory_order_relaxed` to increase the reference count. You are saying that this would be bogus. I strongly doubt that. They cannot afford non-atomic updates, and they usually know what they are doing.

Comment: "Operations on atomic types performed with relaxed ordering don’t participate in
synchronizes-with relationships. Operations on the same variable within a single thread
still obey happens-before relationships, but there’s almost no requirement on ordering relative to other threads." C++ Concurrency in Action, page 150.

Comment: I take it back. In this specific case, the standard specifically says that atomic read-modify-write operations always read the last value in the modification order.